# Term for disappointment of lack of armed conflict

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a term for the disappointment one might feel when an armed conflict, e.g. a civil war, does not occur?

Comment: Do you want a specific term for the lack of armed conflict or will a more general term like "anticlimax" do?

Comment: Disappointed for no war? May we live in boring times?

Comment: There are terms for the love of or keenness for war (like [hawkishness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_hawk)), but you want something more specific than that?

Comment: I propose the new word “Prigozhined”, to mean “disappointed by the lack of follow-through on the part of would-be insurgents, revolutionaries, or free-booters.”

Answer (score 1):

This term isn't specific to military conflict, but I think one could describe certain recent events—we all know what you're talking about, right?—as **anticlimactic.**

[MW defines this as](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anticlimactic) "of, relating to, or marked by anticlimax," where ["anticlimax" means:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anticlimax)

> an event, period, or outcome that is strikingly less important or dramatic than expected